# Positioning horizontal menu inside header

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a website template and I just started with the header and navbar. I'm trying to position a div with some text inside the #header div. I set the position to relative and I used the top property but it's just not moving. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: I assume you tried running your CSS through a linter? And examined the `navbar` element in the style inspector to make sure the styles were being applied?

Comment: @cRover: what i observed is If we have a semicilon, we need to give an extra space between styles

Comment: The supplied link has many different layout options...have a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the semicolon after the `#header` block in your CSS as this is preventing the browser from reading the next rule in the file:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: url("poro.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
};
```

That last semicolon shouldn't be there. The same is true of your semicola following the `#navbar li` and `#header-msg` blocks.

```css
#header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
 background-image: url("poro.jpg");
 background-size: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#navbar {
 position: relative;
 width: 75%;
 height: 100px;
 top: 100px;
}
#navbar li {
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 40px;
 color: blue;
 position: relative;
 left: 350px;
}
#header-msg {
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Experimenting
 </title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="header">

  <div id="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li class="button">Home</li>
    <li class="button">Shop</li>
    <li class="button">Offers</li>
    <li class="button">FAQ</li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="header-msg">
   <h1>We sell stuff.</h1>
   <h3>You buy stuff.</h3>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Note: I made the `#navbar li` have blue text in the snippet so they stand out from the white background.

Comment: I don't think it will prevent the browser from reading the rest of the file. Maybe the next rule.

Comment: @torazaburo You're right. There were later semicola too; updated answer to correct this.

Comment: If we have a semicilon, we need to give an extra space between styles

Answer (score 0):

First delete semicolons after all { }. Next try to set

```
#header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
   background-image: url("poro.jpg");
   background-size: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
}
```

and change position of #header-msg to absolute:

```
#header-msg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Do I need the semi-colons after the right-curly brackets? Also, why does this work?

Comment: No, you should delete semicolons after all brackets. In CSS you should use semicolons inside brackets, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave an extra space after the semicolon.

```css
#header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
 background-image: url("poro.jpg");
 background-size: 100%;
 text-align: center;
};

#navbar {
 position: relative;
 width: 75%;
 height: 100px;
 top: 100px;
};

#navbar li {
 display: inline;
 padding-right: 40px;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
 left: 350px;
};

#header-msg {
 position: relative;
 top: 500px;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
  Experimenting
 </title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="header">

  <div id="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li class="button">Home</li>
    <li class="button">Shop</li>
    <li class="button">Offers</li>
    <li class="button">FAQ</li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="header-msg">
   <h1>We sell stuff.</h1>
   <h3>You buy stuff.</h3>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you change anything besides removing the semi-colon?

Comment: I do not think removing just the `;` is the problem. I did remove the link to a stylesheet.css